# Generate vcard and qrcode - Image not coming through

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I need help with the following code...
I am passing info to generate a vcard. This is in Wordpress using Snippets and ACF custom fields. Everything is working as should except for the images. I am trying to pass the post thumbnail image into the vcard. To pass images into a vcard I believe you need to encode to base64 text. I got this to work.

Next I am trying to generate a qr code as well, using google API. Because I passed the base64 encode into it. When it goes to generate the qrcode using the data google says the URL is too long.

To try to offset this I put the encode base64 into a string and try to pass it this way. Google then gives a different error...

G[oogle Error](https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=H&chl=BEGIN%3AVCARD%0AVERSION%3A3.0%0AN%3ADupre%3BAndy%0AFN%3AAndy%20Dupre%0AORG%3AThe%20Cochran%20Firm%0ATITLE%3AAttorney%0AURL%3BTYPE%3DPREF%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2FCochranFirm.com%20%0AEMAIL%3BTYPE%3Dwork%3Atest%40gmail.com%0ATEL%3BWORK%3BVOICE%3A334-793-1556%0AADR%3BTYPE%3DWORK%3BPREF%3D1%3A%3B%3B123%20Main%20Street%3BAny%20Town%3BCA%3B91921%3B%0APHOTO%3BENCODING%3Db%3BTYPE%3DJPEG%3A.%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wCEAAUFBQUGBQYHBwYJCQgJCQ0MCwsMDRMODw4PDhMdEhUSEhUSHRofGRcZHxouJCAgJC41LSotNUA5OUBRTVFqao4BBQUFBQYFBgcHBgkJCAkJDQwLCwwNEw4PDg8OEx0SFRISFRIdGh8ZFxkfGi4kICAkLjUtKi01QDk5QFFNUWpqjv%2FCABEIAMgAyAMBIgACEQEDEQH%2FxAA1AAAABwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMEBQYHCAEJAQACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgADBAUG%2F9oADAMBAAIQAxAAAADpxl8%2BXHRz%2FR5f51Slb%2FQL3hCarPY7rj6eYdPF58lLU2mFoOHMOrXnz%2Bna7e9IzDNpemxViz19BC1%2B2V%2FTS6fJOXpiDGeho8SAlkfBabnua%2BtvT3hxl8fsDkTAoXoKn2JnxOn2FdnIK0Sbl9Wdk4A%2BHo2Sn2FK%2FDWvOy6F3OFziTa6WU1CyM5jOtTUXaENhGBLOic70%2BIF%2BU65D2iNHpynlbZ7lu%2BwfQwzDWcpmXTx1UdFQw9SsyTiw5dtTtjt1Wem6XZG3ofM0yBtcUa7TMpuMGtE6ieXWkDCi3mgu3w3f5WSSl%2BZmVp8%2BQETVjV5LwlWzq%2Bdx%2Bi5Hy%2BovP0%2Bfz7JuYrVtqboqP58rfd8%2FwBSU7nCfQ9UqsF%2BZscoBsrLiICTSoaz17qZjHmiGRJj0gSwz1JvpCZwmjJ8O9x8Mxq1J1eVy32vp3nDTq7ekoSLedHnt4CQRiKOXPqiKROmKIEOhUutRDmFv32iJd1WoxxjMKijaK6LBe32M57bXs2H4zt4bKbxm96yb9UxfWeSjl0bonid5to79Lw3rEr6XWplrORYpgHiwBhudkdoV63izBwDFt5eF1VweQ4rH6abDENEGWT3DD92o05BquNa9l7DfBLjStfEOEfbUXUaFWTPXnFvQor6nOFJXCh2MGnMG2dq9MX%2BRyqxVm50F9kYmdeI%2B3KYJAGyaTmFiy7K3eKI3p6cWQF3%2Be99KBAX0kK1xpcss%2BjK8DOGiCEcKVsbSyM6OhRtCrM%2Fidtwr2N8%2Fd1KRkTb86hSCSVNFyOXpqxLhmYAX23D6PPBPUjtyXL1g7C9l7Hy50nK4ANQcugJS9Y5fWTkohksxTlrRs46mYirVW2HL4RGWUQRS94gCRFATwooCCH1E6bBZy1XVdg7J4G%2BhtF9JFwACmNZtf8AqZ4prtWcZruOGKzY1lMQKVgmAfTI%2Bxjel9UejwQe%2B%2BeyBLobn5ym5bmiWD6L%2FNr6S49a4MKL%2BIaJtm9dTDwQbdMKdIwhkkYqnh1CXi%2FgiJ%2FFQUPTCAph7J4on4Z3HxLoVBZk%2FVlFRr9AuEPoKJNAoo0cf9wAdKiR%2BaIGe2jtwJW4ACAgAEIcCTwASDwBoVwAY69Ak8UAidb7sBK%2FAAuv%2F8QALBAAAQQCAgEDAwQCAwAAAAAAAQIDBAUABgcREhATIQgUMRUWICIXQSMmMv%2FaAAgBAQABBQBGw1DmTrSOZbcltWBaTnY9HiBPUoHCQM8h2teUZ6ir2bX23IltVzFZISDbAfFoB9vat%2BWpR2wILLYCOh7dv2KyI0VNyIhElMhAxFi%2Bks7JbNhje9qYxnlXd2SxzXuzeN837MX2OebLGOckLxvmerVjHLmvuZtfIFzNz7mzdVAY2Jtel8kWUKUqwr3bNtxlYtAn7exSP22ykiKhJ8fw3bAmFWpcAmPKdeVovHT%2BXHGXH6E0PEWnWde7wHqqse%2BnqlOL%2BnhrJHAdi09O4Z2KEtPDe2tBXFe4oxTAblrLS1t%2BHbLxSX%2FbksSpEguJt7BvF7NcIC922P2ByBszLevXMqVVqnOhGxXkiNAibU6kSt2ZZszGtTnJCpEOl4%2FmGfr4CekPRxiZcZsWl%2FHjS2dikyZTc%2FLu1fYpYr6nHnbSHHXDtIkkO3sKK5FsoUlVJJZi71JotNULjU9Ffq7rUuPGYDfHGszZGvUFamr%2FAEdSnNq1h9ytTqM5oS9MsZVp7kvOTGLCdRcLqs4GkGeoYbFsYu2iJN1Ipplvrbzb12DSrE6upn4UmOtpD0aQk0kVxM7ZIT3vV0WUUfZuvbLMaljJ1VNdh20FCqenjvPo1ryRXtPJ9yaw1LbPwPn0tkeY1NoMV5IGd50Dklps28uqhsTTDinN8bELVx0GlNNrLcyLGmmdBmZGbQnHvdala197ZUqYs6RS7j95JpKmunxbCO0lprrOsWPRPKu%2FpyRytvroics7zEDfNu8pxvnbcU4jnzZRg53t1S5%2FNr88RucGHRc8p1NxVSWVMsqfQ3jjUJx6IIQxl4Bbccycq9j1GFAuNs1tmFMudck0EW5gzLtvx6HWEjFnBi%2BCdPOWXA%2BtoQ59PNPivp2hYv6dU4r6dX8e%2Bn6e3KT9PlujGuEb1nP8PbCnL3Qr%2Bqpn1oOBhHlCjtFCVBKkUF%2FOhPaLtXjL1HY0B7WbxDegV9jE2htRCQo4VfC3mk5LvayGgT4xTeXtdDj%2FALkqDg2OmwbHS4L%2BmOSL2nNx%2BpV5wToZwS4pyYY0iJscSMmQmzW2Itx5NxVB13jqYl%2BrT%2BLMpDEl9g1Xg25jcF8gQkpTIajqbdjQQbiuguRs2JsrY8U44Wm0T5seKgX8v7huch62MeOR9rH6%2BwhY7Cgob2ry%2B%2FLSyqPFIyjqpUwu2Lms0%2Bo31bsdPYxGkx7LwOuwo7Yh%2B0lIdZHsuNqJIJNuj%2Fh7GXCUqay4U2YX2El9pww1M%2BLi3k2ciIlm4huNxpTUlrkncGKGnsaqLYi616fUmj1FxxDTbLLfJexh1%2FTN0s9dlweZKOyiqnQpuvQ3VGIVFWe8faSQfS1UkNqkNIy2nxi0iSwtFnJTIfamONMIWp1UxKSEtlLFtcQK1NhzBIjRri%2Fm3VjWyA7E2izftLbjnZlvmzmMRY1jYOT54dcAblECBsM%2BCui5gmsN0O5UV224n4jp%2FqRlo2pTXi44Z6VJZZdcCDIKQt51CkrJy822kpzectTnkTbqbMddeBMFflYpbkor7FlLknR6qrm1XJFkIVOVZ59AKOBRwPlOMWDzSuJ9hkW%2Btxx8FJOWQHstgDJ6CGlvNoTHStWToznnZqFZV2FtKnTPfOF7oKc7ND4rvLqQzGiRnZDp41dQyjfbcWOw9532rvCo4VfDZ%2BeC7QNW0cHxCSTYpT7aeYqLykctVryGOVatJRy5WhK%2BW4BVyHyQ3Y6uVd55YpXwDmqKA2LfpYRUMqUDQWgqK1Siok4M79CcQc1OzdrLmO6SjzVl5NUxGb4423H%2BPdpjM1elbDYJb4w2sg8Z7MnORK%2BTTyQrO8J7AUetXbD2wbtYJl3iFAZMmLDBPp36qI8gcgulDmrS2rHX1ozZkFSHLBpKbWbHXB0%2BZGbQqziHFWEVbnJluLTcEqzyGeWA%2FFTMMKxU8txfuFCSokn%2BHeFX9wcYPxwfaKl6ssjrYioJbpoflaVURMXU4LCG3m20I2a4Zp9dkOqcdB%2BRneJOJV0rrsPqAbKgP5AntKvhhXSuB7QMWjkkd7G8CmNJdWLLyVFp4shp52PIGc7XS40A4D%2FYn076Kv8AyzIUnHVhS%2B%2Bz3ned%2BneDBjR%2BeI5TbW6O07eWmvTpBttipahEnkrTPaRybqjblhyfr6k8nbQdk2xZwn57zv4KjnfYAOE9AfA79O87OKJ6GJxHYOozFRL1agM8sfFZe115xnLiLa1HYFC91%2B7qKZw%2FK1ElWJPYOdYFdkKBT32rP9YMGFClADAk4j8VCuphLysCeh%2B7bqgsKvnGpXlbu%2Buz2eddmQ3qjrhUrFYE9Z5jPPywgg%2F6BGD%2BCR3nD%2FHrGx0Tram1%2BeBau4MjwkRH25UHH5qLxFghaXUvPNGdYS5LfWEgZ2SSOx454584UKA7zs%2FwR%2BdOkQNY4JWgKUltOFpONf1c0F179m%2B%2Bkq4AU23uO4cP6ndo2HgTbIAsYz8SYok4oYgYOwfjDh%2FJWSnOs6HoT1iVdHaN4kWdL4k511njkKvkTJ2u1iqmiDbqxwk%2F%2FwB2LwehhJ8OQXYzm2nsYrslIABIGd53h%2FPqDhz5ONsggJAz4wkdN%2FOcRcdsQYSvw248B%2F%2FEAEEQAAIBAwICBwQGBwcFAAAAAAECAwAEERIhBTEQEyJBUWFxICMykRRygYKSsTRCUmKhwdEGFTAzQ2ODJDVAc%2FD%2F2gAIAQEABj8A7F9A33xXDdE8ZzM3Jhy0kV8YPoa59Nt%2F65P5ewccquMnH%2FUSfnRRuKW4Yc%2B2K0219BMfBHBPRYfUko1xT0WtHjGBVuPBDSfVFbeBoj0pBn9UVbktXZuXFArxCYY8GNe741cL9817v%2B0E%2FwA80MccLfWRTW91byesVRSyQWrFFI5EUOt4ZCfR67fCiPR67dhMKOYplwMkkVLb25eG0aRmVF5nJ76%2F1D5ZpXi1IRuDnBqKw4%2BzdS%2ByTPuVPr3irIpdRMNEnJvHFdmVD6GuJYYHZaiH7oqIY7jS7fqij6V9ooFU1HTUK6VGMnIr9Cs%2FsYVbkW0cYeTDEP3AV17I4JkcDDcgDXYuJ0rMfE5R6rXu%2BMfNKjji4rE2vPNSKjT6VbuXcAAE1yt39Gr9Cjb0kFG1IAS3b3oB%2BOT%2BgreMHFbIBW1NHIAcjwqUPM3Ww4BP7S8hyrsX0y%2BjsKYf3tOM8%2FeGjAeMzGPwJoKnFWIGwBCmrSWWXU7RKSaO45GoiqKdciqc0q9SBkY2NW1u1oxLjmD5127Gwf7WH5g1DLJw%2BCFPpCq0kb778u6luU%2Fs%2FNMrzSgSpIva0sR412uCcSj%2BrJn8mreLjEXqHP5ZrP0%2FiC%2BTRN%2FNas%2Br4nKzFH2Mf9QKHW3yB2vIwcryC1txC1auJSpPAWS3kIKtvyqduZLE%2FOu24J7wK922TWmQ0BFMpY92d64YZoleN51jdGGQRJtTdZwu2YgE4Ee9Xd4LGGLEYMartkmrKNbA%2FSZI89lmycCpSk0scUMJdhnvHdVolrO7e6GkHmPWmh60agmc%2BtIBOo0yRn%2BNIetRqtZjIiJFzPPNfo6%2FY%2F8AUVDbRcNMxe5TYSAY0gmrSyuOGTa4Z5wWBTBzIWrtWdwPug1vBOP%2BNq7etfWNv6VYdZIA0cMrISDswxiuKS3skYCyRlQRgdp8GudsflV2gjgy8LrtjvFXaxczIR8q09Quc0gPwZoGJNqQSQp9ZNiK4AUGZZZoV%2B1Xq2iiue1LqQ5XcbZp4JbkD6MmsbfGBkCrHiTx6JGtzgeCigulTmzdj86tJWtxj6OMDOOVajAwypyQfGgjawoIONXhQHh02e2cXK%2FxBFTRAY0XMy%2FI%2BxYkqM9XL%2FKrxzGg%2BktAw271bDVvAn4avrizijjmXR2woyAzAGkd92ZmLeua1AYqMPzbOkelMEdWZQNS%2BGaFcOu4H0SwSFlYcwa4XxWWd%2FpJjYOMZDYJWuKPLPvqbRlNwo5Vwazto8SSKEZT4YqCG4kUB7VlwvkajiT4Y10qPL2f%2B9KfWNKQPxWA6GDj3aipAl7akO5c5Tvat3sH9UrtW1g1dvhVk3pIRUEz8EtsIGGBP41bZ4GiNFMsmRP4V2%2BDuPSUVdWEvDpkEyY1hgcEcjUSNzVmBI89%2BgO7IpPiaJBj6zGG38KKg5APP1qAawgWQMzHkByJOatrWHjFpoijCjMgFX5j4paOrruqyDOTVqf7ztdQVNJ6xcqcVBHFcxyPHC%2BrQc949raW5H3qjMV5cAmRU38zW3Epq24rJW3GDW3GKghHFQesDHNbcTQ1tdRGvjiP3qeW4QNHG%2BxU5xnxrTIMjvr3dojjzodbZRjwyKIxgVB9FtHaGUE5GO1pNbcLmNOX4VcYXn2K1vwu6CnkerNQM9tNErIwJZCBQ6cs6j1Na5Z8DyBNZzJjzjf%2BlQNM7DVcQgdhu9vSv85h6xv%2FAEr9LA9Qa%2FTY62v4fxVw9Bfwk6JdtYr9Ki%2FEK2uI%2FwAQraeP8Qq4hdo2V42BBI76aSHsgk5Xu2pwMAgHFIr86Vjyq2iyMwtKvzwaFXnLOkVECRlQM%2BWKVlTPgQK7hRLudqUDO7CnBt1JPImkV4lPP59FiBja%2Btz8nrlWp8ADvNKdCsW5U6LbwntcyO6uGzT8NjTHWIHAB%2BKt4UP2VjqI%2FwAIr9Fi%2FCKdjaxEKpPwjuq5UDSC5IHhmhihqodWmIxzc8hT3Nq6AwspbrOT6jg1DeW5w%2FKWPWco1XjjUSAO%2Bs4AOkCoDqYZUd9D37j7aY9c%2BMGvjJrc1GA2O0e7otc8vpUJ%2BTdEkZk0lhRYOxVANRalSNFMiqe3jnVvqfSik4JpNciSoSPUUzl9Okbg0JIm1LRiSZRdXDqgHeqNzNFZV9GHMUJv8yAsAHBwd%2FI1HPfjAOCIgfzIoIgCqvICoeFxN2I8SS%2BvIChNbTFc7Mp3Vx4Gp4ruNraWTwOpa1211HKMDOls4pFJ5fyoZatJbatt%2BiLK57VDU4H21DhtXv4zt5NWQwNAoNlGKnRWyG5g0uVCIF51EqnYUhbfNFridEAHLO9PbWLLCvj%2FAKhqJp5GbVIo3OeZqKQ89O%2FkRsaJMxMCkrEgPwhdtQ8Sak4VcHPVjMD9xA5ippHcAIhck9wXck1c3T7GRyceA5AVhX01u5Ld5NBoLp09DSRXkCTqO%2F4WqPqblUmP%2Bk5wfs8aPhR8ehCCBgmvi%2BdDBz21%2FOtZyCOVMywBdY3NEhdNEMxAPPauqnug0qrq6tee9GGzAhTxHxUZJpmZj4mvE%2BJqzH%2B8v8DmneFxifVkMeQxjIp0jOEhOnrPMbkLioZow0d1bOdZU76x40LRHJlvJMMTz6tOftZSRlPiDUsN1KZJ7Nwmo8yj8qPTpI3rOSe2u1KmvJPMVhvgzQ6lcnvq%2Bv55fdW8LOw%2BqOVXNzPKXklcsxPn086sFZNQMwyPGrqdsLDbxnA9NgB6mideCT25D%2BrnfStcWt0wCoibHflsjergI2YbbEMf3OZ%2Bft8Rsnfe4tlKeZiNHoWtX923H8KKixnAJrUeGzE1gcNm%2BYoEcNk%2BYq6sYLRoevkRSSe4HV7NgT3Ox%2BSmrW2zgzSB2%2BqlDSdJUbt%2BwD4fvGuNXUeFaO3XSD8RdyVTV%2BeKJJySTv7dhexnBgmVz5ryYfaKyOR6F8WYit%2BHEerrRlksgFH74pzDbAhWwcsBWTbRj1kreGEf8lWvD7jQJQplYKc%2FHy9nhyZwGkwflToh93AoRfAYoBeyRvvyT94%2BLGjaoCqFxI5PNyBgE%2FPoz7A6EYdxFcMvEO0tup9CBgiudWmD%2Buc%2FKs9am%2FnTaplzp8auQ0ygCY1kTrTe%2FU%2BlcVmD6kSTqk9E7NH2ILkc4ySPkRTSM2XYlix%2FM1hRuN9%2B795qJJySeftHoPjU9qTk2twfsWTtUQRv41ajIHaNN7tPiPdTDQnxDurinwHF24G3gBRYKmQfCuKcT2EkEDaPrt2Vp3Y5ZiSSfOj0mgdtj312eZ7W%2FwA9TUF5A7%2BbeZ%2FwuLWRO00Cyj1Q1zq0%2BsabmN8195fzriSIuxn1fNRR1g48KsODplDOxmlH7ibL7RrSe1nuPeaJ1aj3msf4ArhSyfBNrhP31IFdiVhUWiVToJPzqN%2BIT9SrkgEoSP4A0Qt51h8BE1XDIZDqIIIj57UnVJOT39jFXt4uRCmmKIeCxjH%2FAIXCrgHHU3kLH01jpeGYLNBIKMvDnE8X7B2cVtw9%2FmKveIXFpoigjLElhzOwos3Mk%2BzvRrH%2FAMKz3e02BnAyfYiH7RApSy4BUHole0uWCF9423U5pIuKWrRP%2B2m61rs%2BKQP%2B4Wwd%2FWrSwSQE3k2Wwf1IvY59GKzXqfb%2FALX3U8QJ%2Bhm3tWbksr76qZG5qSNvL06NqiY7EMD8qs54jqSSFHU%2BTDomltYnZ0XXJGBkoB3nHd51uMVlHZT4g4qGOad5BGpxqOcaq39rFA429u4v59vpMU583eQmJBROMdI1biuAa%2BYs46KkEbZzVwj8ns5Fqa4jiayucfHD8J9UppLIxX0X%2B2dD%2Fhap7eaMpJExV1PMMuxHST7Ok%2BX8PazXAOB2zsOHcOs4wV5a5yNTufQnArIoV5VBbQRGSSdwiKO9m2FcMsGOpre2jjY%2BajBqYocARjNBPG2lp9%2B0Bg0M%2BArjj28gkia9mYOORyx6cf4e9ch0YNbGoeOcQVHvH3tlDBhGhHxbd5rlUyK2AUzX%2F8QALBEAAgEDBAECBgEFAAAAAAAAAQIAAxEhBBIxQSIQExQgMlFhcSRCgZGx4f%2FaAAgBAgEBPwD2aQ4DRtMvRnwzdGDTPjMFB5YKpB7jVKS8vaJnK5G0yngtKBF2jtmEkC8FR7CIQzgAypYMfO0324qSnuYXvC79CVy5qkcxg7HjM0FSolXZwIH3dGZtcQtV7MLVYdQBjes07gVkNhiV2Bqv4RWTtZQrIAFs30z3Uvy0avtcm15UqOHD2xKepHvgkYlN1ZAQYaqIDfEfVZ8BKlao5yZeCtSJwM%2FqGrSOT%2Fqb6B52%2FwCIGoixn8cypTybZEqgbeZRo%2B5UXodxEpjgyrtVCbwm%2BZeZ%2B0S1xLr9oSlj%2BISpAM8Y220qinKD2rAdHEFg0KB%2BeItGkv8ARCqW4jMAf%2BQAA8x22jGTAy7CRz3eM10QrKaOwziVwFVQI4Npp0u1z1Cbc5isoxOZ1Ku3eYWb3QTErOl2I5MSujqB4j8Sy4xkS5lZsgR2ORKQ2oPQgS1jiHAlQ%2BZxFGmJ6MqjRg2ewiLpeUCkzHpW%2BoGKu6oPkMJjKL8Tf5Ahbf3muN6osZoVO0n0xK3IlIAAmX9AJ1FvbEIuYdFV3nzvaPoXY7jkyggp0gJcQteNZhALAD1UTuVHdGwZ8Q%2F2EtSfg2MqUNSpuCpWGYtNphWGdQRTkiZvNUSCCJeHwa%2FUDgi0Ywy5%2BQQgD9wYjKrYMNFJUA9kfuLDz8xg9BCMz%2F%2FEACkRAAICAQQBBAIBBQAAAAAAAAECAAMREiExQQQQEyJRYaEgMDJCUpH%2F2gAIAQMBAT8AFrwWnsT3B3PdUQ2r9QZcgjqCp24Ro6lDgw9S8cRBAATiFB9Q4UZI%2FUXBHEwD1%2B42kQBc8zxvbVFJgesLnK4nnpW9eocwoR2IV%2B4EIgDdcwV3nqXofbYa2lWSgJbmEEjZpbXacnPcrpuZlAA3i%2BOWUAnBEqpRqimd5Z4hNWheTLUtrtZSNxn9QJY4GJX4xA%2BRiVVpwPQ1sBuNoK2AwB%2B4EbrP%2FTCrkdxTapDDVtF8nV8uCZSw57lnlmpdXJHEd2csT3Kz8hAs4mof7CMDpM0t9zQc8xQwJnygBIlZt64l6r7OCflzCNQhLIdobbD3Czk8wh8zqDmZ3AmrBIhsUSpiSTAGFQcHYy5iFx9wHEtDNxGLKdxBviDOIQAIFyQBLFKsYWJ9KFzHoQeMCOu%2BjLWJc7TDZnylgyhzFH9sA2G8JsxEN3UY25%2BRgAgxmeIAzYE8mzR4rdnj8D8CamO5mTBmckiAEHELkGMrESoMAcy88TeCeCuxM85ixCZ46%2BoBMenDAx8Bo5GqZH3A2kbGWPqbMC55gAEpZlORtGbUxM69eoiI67iHxKSYC687wWJj8wL3B6A4%2FgV2EInjAFSDMRVLLzvChB%2FoE52ncDMo2OItlmJUTqjHiHn169P8vTqAnVLCdUrYhFn%2F2Q%3D%3D.%0AEND%3AVCARD)

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
    

function hj_create_vCard( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * In production code, $slug should be set only once in the plugin,
     * preferably as a class property, rather than in each function that needs it.
     */
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // only update the attorneys custom post type on save
    if ( "attorney" != $post_type ) return;

    $vpost = get_post($post_id);
    
    $fname = get_field('first_name',$post_id); // get attorney first name
    $lname = get_field('last_name',$post_id); // get attorney last name
    $att_name = $fname.' '.$lname; // combine first and last name for vcard Name
    $fullname = $fname.'-'.$lname;  // combine first and last name for file Name
    $formatedname = $lname.';'.$fname;  // combine first and last name for file Name
    $att_imgurl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    
    $filename = $fullname.".vcf";
    //$filename = $vpost->post_name.".vcf";
   
    header('Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
   
    $data.="BEGIN:VCARD\n";
    $data.="VERSION:3.0\n";
    $data.="N:".$formatedname."\n"; // get attorney full  name
    $data.="FN:".$att_name."\n"; // get attorney full  name
    $data.="ORG:The Cochran Firm\n"; //set org name
    $data.="TITLE:Attorney\n"; // set job title
    $data.="URL;TYPE=PREF:https://CochranFirm.com \n"; // set job title
    $data.="EMAIL;TYPE=work:" .get_field('att_email',$vpost->ID)."\n";  // get acf field value
    $data.="TEL;WORK;VOICE:" .get_field('att_phone',$post_id)."\n";  // get acf field value
    $data.="ADR;TYPE=WORK;PREF=1:".get_field('att_address',$post_id)."\n";  // get acf field value
    
    //details for setting an image, it must first be encoded at https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image and changed to base64 plain text
    $image = file_get_contents($att_imgurl); // get file contents from thunbnail    
    $encode = base64_encode($image); //encode image
    update_field('profile_image',$encode,$post_id); //update the acf field for preview
    $data.="PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:.$encode.\n"; //pass the data to thee vcard
    
    $data.="END:VCARD";
    
    $filePath = get_home_path()."/wp-content/vcard/".$filename; // you can specify path here where you want to store file.
    $file = fopen($filePath,"w");
    fwrite($file,$data);
    fclose($file);
    
    //Update the acf field value with the url of the qrcode
    $fileURL= get_site_url()."/wp-content/vcard/".$filename;
    update_field('att_vcard', $fileURL,$post_id); 
    
    //Generatee and store qrimage
    $qrimageurl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=H&chl=' .urlencode($data);
    update_field('qr_image',$qrimageurl,$post_id);

    
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'hj_create_vCard' );
```

Comment: what's the Url you are trying to convert to QR?